# How to convert spaces into tabs in ruby on rails correctly?

Tags: html, ruby

I'm converting linebreaks and extra spaces.

```
def simple_format_plus(string)
   (h(string).gsub(/\n/, '<br/>').gsub('  ', "\t")).html_safe
end
```

In my views I'm calling:

```
<p><%= simple_format_plus(post.content) %></p>
```

However the html output doesn't show the "\t" part. I've even tried disabling the css, but the problem still persists. For some reason I can't display more than one space in succession.

```
There   are   3   spaces   instead   of   1   in   this   line   .
```

still displays as:

```
There are 3 spaces instead of 1 in this line .
```

If I inspect the `<p>` element the extra spaces show up in the developer console however, but not in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tab can't be interpreted in HTML. You can use &nbsp for three or the number of times you want. The helper method can be re-written like

```
def simple_format_plus(string)
 (h(string).gsub(/\n/, '<br/>').gsub(' ', "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp")).html_safe
```

end

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Consecutive space characters are interpreted in HTML as a single space. If you want to display each space character as is in the source HTML file, then surround that part with `<pre>` ... `</pre>`.

Comment: Indeed `<pre>` seem to work, however It also makes the lines not break in the paragraph. With css on, since I'm using bootstrap, it badly messes up the styling.